# Subscribe to CollectionChanged event of unknown type ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of a property at runtime in a generic `DataTemplateSelector` and can't seem to find a way to get the generic form of the `ObservableCollection<>`.

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    var ds = item as Orders_VM; 
    ds.SelectedOrders.CollectionChanged += MyGenericChangedEvent;
}
```

Which i'm trying to generalize so I can use with different ViewModels and property names.

```
public String myCollectionPropertyName { get; set; }
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(myCollectionPropertyName);
    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)propertyInfo).CollectionChanged += MyGenericChangeEvent;
}
```

Comment: Please stop adding the backticks to the formatting. If you indent a code block by four spaces, it will format the code. The backticks are for `inline code`, you don't need them for a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CollectionChanged` event isn't generic, so don't worry about that. If it were, handling it might indeed be difficult and complicated. `DataTemplateSelector` isn't generic at all. Do you possibly mean "generic" in the colloquial sense, rather than the .NET sense of a class or method that has one or more type parameters? It's best to use terms like "generic" only in their conventional programming sense, so as to avoid confusion.

Your problem here is that you are getting an object of type `PropertyInfo`, and trying to cast it to `INotifyCollectionChanged` for some reason. Obviously you can't do that. You want the actual value of that property on that particular instance of the class, not the `Type` class's *description* of the class member.

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(myCollectionPropertyName);

    var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(item);

    var incc = propertyValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    incc.CollectionChanged += yGenericChangeEvent;
```

Once you get it working, you could condense it a bit:

```
public DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    var incc = (INotifyCollectionChanged)item.GetType()
        .GetProperty(myCollectionPropertyName).GetValue(item);

    incc.CollectionChanged += MyGenericChangeEvent;
```

Comment: Yes, I was using it in the colloquial sense.

Thank you, that works perfectly for me!  I know I'd tried GetValue at some point, but just didn't take it far enough to casting as the INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: @Brandon The one thing to watch out for is the possibility that `item` doesn't actually have an observable collection property by that name. But my guess is that your code guarantees in other ways that it does.